# Firemonkey: label cutting accentuation

Tags: android, label, firemonkey

I'm developing an app for android using Rad Studio 10.1 and I'm having trouble with a new font that I'm trying to implement into my project. The problem is, I have to use accentuation in my app because is for portuguese language users, and portuguese has a lot of accentuation. I found a good font on the internet and I want to use, but when I put into a label, the label cuts the top part of the text. An image to explain better:

[image]

As you can see, just the accentuation of the top are being cutted, should be a 'Ã'. The bottom accentuation 'Ç' are just normal, and this just happen with UpperCase texts. Someone have any idea why this is happening?

EDIT: Aditional information: The TLabel is alredy set on Client Alignment